# How to understand the contractionしていて、/-てて

Tags: verbs, contractions, て-form

I am trying to better understand this sentence:

> 金さんは、微妙なニュアンスまで気にされてて、すごいですね。
>
> It's amazing how interested you are in these subtle nuances.

Is the following an accurate understanding of this contraction?
Written in what I perceive as basic, plain Japanese (without honorifics), perhaps the sentence would read as thus:

> 金さんは、微妙なニュアンスまで気にしている。それは、すごいことだ。

Then the " いる。それは、" can be contracted to

> 金さんは、微妙なニュアンスまで気にしていて、すごい。

Then the する is put into 敬語 and further contracted.

> 金さんは、微妙なニュアンスまで気にされてて、すごいですね。

I know the order of this process is arbitrary, but is my understanding correct?
If anyone could explain what the していて、/-てて is doing specifically, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Can I ask where you found that sentence? I wonder if a small つ was omitted. "されてって" I'm not sure if that makes any more sense or not...

Comment: A Japanese native wrote this to me, and the other examples were part of her explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of ている can be found [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/4536/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B/). していて comes from する+ている.

And てる てて are short forms of ている ていて. These short forms should be avoided in formal reading and writing, as they are less formal, and are still being argued whether they should considered correct Japanese.

Comment: is ている exactly the same in nuance and meaning as していて?

Comment: "still being argued whether they should  be   considered correct Japanese." そうですかね。。。