# Meaning of て form plus てね in dialog

Tags: grammar, meaning, て-form, casual

I've come across a portion of dialog, which has some grammar that I have not seen before. Focusing on the portion in bold, what is the purpose of て form plus てね? What does てね mean and is it a shortened version of something?

> **待っててねー**！！ キミのこと　すぐに見つけるからーーー！！！
>
> My translation: Wait!! Pal, because I'm coming to find you right now!!!

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/948/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3945/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25452/9831

Comment: So 待っててねー just means "Wait (and continue to wait)" with a ね ending. So then I guess this really translates to "Keep waiting!". Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

待っててね is an abbreviation for 待っていてね.

待っていてね = 待っていて + ね

待っていて = (待っている、の連用形、待ってい) + て(終助詞)

待っている = 待って + いる

待って = 待ちて(=待つ、の連用形、待ち、+ て(接続助詞)) の 音便

Phew.

Basically, て of 終助詞 means a request or a desire.
て+ね is not that different, but I feel the latter has a slight stronger intention for confirmation.

Comment: Minor quibble, but isn't verb-ending て categorized as a 接続【せつぞく】助詞【じょし】 or "conjunctive particle", rather than a 終【しゅう】助詞【じょし】 or "terminating particle"?  It's the ね that's the 終【しゅう】助詞【じょし】, not the て.