# usage of the second “て” in this sentence

Tags: grammar, usage

“よく晴れててキャンプ日和だよ”.

I am confused about the second "て”　here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand the contractionしていて、/-てて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/how-to-understand-the-contraction%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a6)

Comment: Also: [What does the final て in 待ってて signify?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/948)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`晴{は}れてて` is a contraction of `晴{は}れていて`, with the verbs `晴{は}れる` and `いる`.

Answer (score 4):

晴れる=get sunny

晴れて=get sunny and...

晴れている=be sunny

晴れていて=be sunny and...